# My json array is echoing directly to the page for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I am 'echoing' a json array back to ajax, but it is printing the entire array to the screen. I am at my wits end! Can someone see anything wrong with the following code that would cause this?

My ajax call:

```
theUrl = 'myphpquerypage.php?id=somenumber'

$.getJSON(theUrl, function(data) {        
    var content = "";
    $.each(data, function(index, array) {
        content += "<div>" + array.filename + "</div>";
        $(content).appendTo('#myContentDivTag');
```

myphpquerypage.php:

```
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $rows = array();
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("call getimages(?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

The echo is causing this to go directly to the screen (nothing shows up in #myContentDivTag):

```
[{"filename":"img4dc458200caa7.jpg"},{"filename":"img41b65171bd651.jpg"},    {"filename":"img41be6c0eae1a4.jpg"},{"filename":"img41e5d5eede9da.jpg"},    {"filename":"img41e5d64383039.jpg"},{"filename":"img422fb82b3768a.jpg"},    {"filename":"img422fc528cc8d1.jpg"}]
```

Thanks everyone, any help would be greatly appreciated. I have spent hours trying different things. Obviously I am getting the json encoded array back, but I cannot get it to properly display.

Comment: is echo json_encode($rows) the only output that your php script has? make sure you are only outputting json, and not anything else.

Comment: Hi RPM, yes it is the only output in the php script. The php I posted here is the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose we have different ways of dealing with JSON data in ajax requests, and though yours isn't wrong, mine seems to work ;)

Here is an example of how I'd do it, seems to work fine:http://jsfiddle.net/5YWpr/3/
(Note, it uses jsfiddle's ajax tester, so it posts sample json data to be returned, why the ajax request looks weird, use the one in this thread if you just want to insert the code).

Javascript:

```
$.ajax("myphpquerypage.php",
{
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get" /*can also be post*/,
    data: {id: "somenumber"},
    success: function(data)
    {
        var content = "";
        for (var key in data)
        {
            content += "<div>" + data[key].filename + "</div>";
        }

        $("#test").append(content);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
before div

<div id="test">
</div>

after div
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Heya mazzzzz. At first I tried your code, and the same thing happened. So that made me dive a little deeper into why this was. Turns out, although your code and my code are actually good, the problem was actually with the dynamic tabs that I didn't even mention in here. So because you posted this, I was able to try different things and find the problem. So I thank you!

Comment: Oh, haha, I really didn't think the code you posted caused it (I couldn't find an issue, so I just rewrote it hoping that would fix it).  Haha, I'm happy to be your rubber ducky xD (for those who didn't get that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).